# How to plot the graph(line) from a file in java?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net

I have a directory containing list of files.

Those files have some list of values as x and y ordered as line by line.

And my question is just I would like to read those files one by one and to plot line graphs based on those values. Could you please help me for that?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [JFreeChart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFreeChart) in the past to do something similar. You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/).